# When I call my function from my header and implementation file to my main file, I do not get any output

Tags: c++, function

So I have 3 files in a single folder, my main file (Q1.cpp), my header file (pa2Functions.h), and my implementation file, (pa2Functions.cpp). When I call my function, I don't get any output and I am extremely confused as to why. I have included the contents of all 3 files below.

**pa2Functions.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void initialize();
```

**pa2Functions.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pa2Functions.h"
using namespace std;

void initialize(){
     cout << "hello" << endl;}
```

**Q1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pa2Functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    void initialize();
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ Q1.cpp pa2Functions.cpp -o Output
```

But when I run the output I just don't get anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main`, remove the `void` in front of `initialize`. You're declaring the function again, not calling it.

```
int main(){
    initialize();
}
```